# What is the installation path of AdoptOpenJDK 8.232 in appVeyor in the macos image?

Tags: java, macos, appveyor

I am trying to change the JDK from version 13 that comes by default to version 8 in Appveyor using the macOS image that according to [their documentation is already preinstalled](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/macos-images-software/).

## Attempts

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_232`
```

> /usr/local/Cellar/appveyor-build-agent/7.0.2546/bash-shell.sh: line 62: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_232: No such file or directory

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home`
```

> /usr/local/Cellar/appveyor-build-agent/7.0.2546/bash-shell.sh: line 62: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home: No such file or directory

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 8 --exec javac -version`
```

> Unable to find any JVMs matching version "8".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it thanks [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697203/java-home-on-mac?rq=1).

```
- export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_232)
```

As you can see I'm asking the program java_home for the installation path of the version `1.8.0_232`.